# Huge issues with Curvature baking

Tags: uv, baking

Dear fellow blenderers,

I am having a really bad time with my new project. I am modelling a corridor and the model itself is quite simple, lots of flat surfaces with minimal use of booleans. The UV unwrap seems fine with the grid applied to it, but then when I try to see how the curvature bakes (using the TexTools addon), the whole thing is riddled with scratches, weird lines all throughout the surface of the object. The same happens if I try and bake the curvature inside Substance Painter.

[image: here are the infamous scratches]
In the picture above you can see the scratches I am talking about.

[image: the UV grid]
In the image above you can see one of the first attempts of UV unwrapping it, the grid is fine.

[image]

[image]
These two show the streaks on all of the objects - the only thing I know is that some of the issues, the cleaner lines, are due to overlapping UVs, an issue easily fixed.

I didn't find any solutions online and even after posting on r/blenderhelp I didn't get any answers. I don't know what to do anymore, I am no master in UV unwrapping, but these unwraps are far from atrocious - as I said, the square grid appears to be quite fine.

I attached the .blend file [HERE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t64AQweKA1RGJjac2OxIg988EEC7dVDT?usp=sharing), so feel free to check out the mess that the curvature is, I can't stand it anymore and I hate not being able to solve this issue - also because I am paying for the Substance subscription without being able to use it due to the curvature issue.

EDIT 1:
Here are two pictures explaining what I mean by the fact that the same vertex connecting from one island to another is causing these lines across the baked image. Please Observe the highlighted verts and where the lines are.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Depends how you bake maybe, using Substance? Also you mention that there're overlapping UVs, did you try to rebake once you position islands to avoid overlapping? The lines look like result of overlapping UVs

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried separating the unwrap more by increasing the Margin setting when unwrapping. Or how do you do that. The more times I do this process over and over again (I am at about a week of banging my head against this wall), I see that these lines are like connections between vertices across UV islands, the lines extend from Vertex A on Island A to Vertex A on Island B, basically the same vert on two different islands. It's weird..

Comment: @MrZak I edited the post and uploaded two images depicting what I mean to say in the last comment.

Comment: First off, try to triangulate all geometry first, then bake. Ngons can provide quite unexpected behaviour for unwrapping when being concave. Second, show a screenshot of full mesh object UV map for which curvature is baked (edit mode > select all > UVs in the map)